# How should I define the type of a promise call back in Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using Typescript and AngularJS. Here's an example of what I am doing:

I have this:

```
    this.userService.registerUser(
        this.registerData.userName,
        () => {
            self.registerData.error = false;
            self.registerData.message = self.registerData.userName + " has been registered";
            self.clearRegisterData();
        })
    }
```

and the function I call is:

```
 registerUser = (
        userName: string,
        successCallback) => {   // << What's the type of successCallback ????????

        this.$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/api/Account/Register",
            data: {
                userName: userName,
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                confirmPassword: confirmPassword
            }
        })
            .success((data) => {
                if (typeof successCallback === 'function') {
                    successCallback(data);
                }
            });
    };
```

I am just showing part of my code but what I would like to know is what's the type of the successCallback parameter?  The parameter must be a function but is there some special way I should define it ?  Also if defined correctly am I right to assume that there would be no need for the check to see if "typeof successCallback === 'function'" ?

Comment: `successCallback:Function` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The bad answer but the one you asked for

You can do it inline quite easily

```
 registerUser = (
        userName: string,
        successCallback: (data)=>any) => {
```

Basically you are saying that it must be okay with taking some *data* argument and I do not care what it returns.

## You don't need to accept a callback if you are returning a promise

You should do:

```
 registerUser = (
        userName: string):ng.IPromise<any> => {   // No callback

        return this.$http({    // RETURN the promise
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/api/Account/Register",
            data: {
                userName: userName,
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                confirmPassword: confirmPassword
            }
        })
    };
```

And then use it at the callsite:

```
this.userService.registerUser(this.registerData.userName)
    .then(() => {                                             // Note `then`
        self.registerData.error = false;
        self.registerData.message = self.registerData.userName + " has been registered";
        self.clearRegisterData();
    })
```

Comment: Very rightly said, i should have mentioned in my answer as well (as i mentioned in a comment in the Richard Morgan's answer). Passing around callbacks are bad pattern, should really utilize promise pattern which gives lots of advantages.. +1. Loved the heading _"The bad answer but the one you asked for"_ :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Function` type

```
 registerUser = (
    userName: string,
    successCallback : Function) => {
```

Or extend a Function type for callbacks:-

```
   export interface CallBackFunction extends Function {
        (data:any):void; 
    }
```

and

```
registerUser = (
        userName: string,
        successCallback : CallBackFunction) => {
```

or just

```
 registerUser = (
        userName: string,
        successCallback : (data:any)=>void) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are just wanting to know how to declare a function type for your successCallback parameter. As mentioned in some other answers there are some other available patterns in angular for promises, but the syntax for declaring your function's type would be:

```
successCallback: (data: TypeOfYourData) => ReturnType
```

You can be as generic as you want if you don't have much type information about your parameter or return type:

```
successCallback: (data: any) => any
```

Or you could be very specific:

```
successCallback: (data: MyAwesomeClass) => boolean
```

Or if you don't have a return type:

```
successCallback: (data: SomeClass) => void
```

Answer (score 0):

DefinitelyTyped has definitions for Angular, which includes an IPromise interface you can use as the type.

This basic guide will you through installing the TypeScript Definition Manager and downloading / including the angular type definitions:
https://coderwall.com/p/qsrzyq

Comment: Right, if the OP has bee returning the promise from the method then it would be something like `ng.IPromise<specificTypeOrAny>` but it seems like here the method has a callback argument (and question is asking about what type that argument should be) and does not really utilize the promise pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
 :ng.IPromise<someResopnse>;
```

and for example

```
export interface someResopnse {
     username: string;
     picture: string 
}
```

etc ..